# In Magento 2, What is use of setIsObjectNew while saving a model factory object?

Tags: magento-2.1, cli

Just curious to know What is use of setIsObjectNew while saving a model factory object, I see most of the time while creating console command it's set to true ?

Below is sample code used in Console command execute method:

```
$item = $this->itemFactory->create();
$item->setName($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_NAME));
$item->setDescription($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_DESCRIPTION));
$item->setIsObjectNew(true);
$item->save();
```

Thanks